# Subsecond datetimes to numeric

Tags: r, posixct

What is the easiest way of a subsecond `POSIXct` (i.e. fractional seconds) type to numeric?

Consider:

```
options(digits.secs = 3)
z <- 1579598122120
dttm <- as.POSIXct((z + 0.1)/1000, origin = "1970-01-01") # avoid rounding down: milliseconds are not exactly representable
print(dttm)
#[1] "2020-01-21 10:15:22.120 CET"
```

From `dttm`, how do I best recover `z`?

I originally expected the following would simply give me the fractional seconds since the epoch:

```
as.numeric(dttm)
[1] 1579598122
```

Searching the web and reading the documentation seems to only give me the solution to the inverse problem. My best solution at the moment is awkward and involves string manipulation of `format(dttm, "%OS3")` pasted together with the above.

I cannot seem to break-upen the object with `str(dttm)`, `unclass(dttm)` and recover the value from there. Likewise `as.double(dttm)` does not work.

Comment: I don't get your question. It does what you expect. It just doesn't print the fractional digits (as usual per default settings):  `sprintf("%.3f", as.numeric(dttm))`

Comment: Or see `all.equal(as.numeric(dttm) * 1000, z)`.

Comment: Arh, doh. I see, it's just a printing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this was simply a printing issue of the number:

```
print(as.numeric(dttm), digits = 14)
#[1] 1579598122.1201
```

A blunder on my part.